# In Spritekit swift it says: Expected Declaration

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I was programming in SpriteKit swift and all of a sudden I got this error saying,

> "Expected Declaration"

Here is the code of where I'm getting the error:

```
    for touch in touches {
            print(touch)
        }

    func Enemies(){
        print("enemies")
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Comment: I used this code and I don't get the error. Please show some more. You are mostly likely missing a bracket or parenthesis somewhere.

Comment: I just updated that so now you can check it out.

Comment: Where exactly is the error happening?

Comment: At the for touches in touches{

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you cannot declare a for statement wherever you would like. You most likely will need to put it in the `touchesBegan` method.